# Jenkins webhook returns a 403

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket

**Introduction**

I am integrating BitBucket with Jenkins.  I have created the webhook in BitBucket. This webhook has a URL, which if I enter into a  browser triggers the Jenkins build (works as expected). However if I trigger the webhook by pushing some code  to the BitBucket  repository, it gets a `403` error trying to call the exact same URL.

**Question**

How do I configure the webhook to invoke Jenkins?

**More Info**

I have followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NzFYxhU-CBY) youtube tutorial exactly.

In this  tutorial they disable `CSRF Protection`.

[image]

But in my version of Jenkins (2.375.2), this is not avaialble that I can see.

[image]

**Jenkins Config**

Dashboard -> pow-wow (my project) -> Configuration -> Build Triggers ->

[image]

**BitBucket Config**

Bitbucket -> Repositories -> pow-wow (my repo) -> Repository Settings -> Webhooks ->

[image]

I use the Jenkins URL for the project:

URL: https://xxxxxxxx/job/BitBucket%20PowWow/build?token=jenkinsToken

**Problem**

If I enter this URL into  a browser, it triggers the build and works.  However if I do a `git push` BitBucket triggers the webhook which calls this URL, and returns a 403 error.

**Jenkins Security**

Dashboard -> Manage Jenkins -> Configure Global Security

[image]

Comment: I have tried removing the `%20' characters and replacing them with a `space` character, but it still gets a `403` error. i.e. `...job/BitBucket PowWow/build?token=jenkinsToken`

Comment: I have also tried including a Jenkins user credentials, but it still returns a 403 when called from BitBucket but works by just entering the url into a browser.  e.g. `https://user-name:password@xxxxxxxx/job/BitBucket%20PowWow/build?token=jenkinsToken`.

Comment: I think the issue may be due to I need to disable `CSRF Protection`.  In my version of  Jenkins (2.375.2), I am not sure if this is available.

Comment: However, Jenkins recommends not to disable it. https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/security/csrf-protection/

Comment: ANSWER: Need to use an api token, here is how: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=faKCng8brkE